Why is a resolution of portrait mode 480 x 640 described as 4 : 3 instead of 3 : 4?
As I've read that:

The aspect ratio of an image is the ratio of its width to its height.
For instance, if a rectangle has an aspect ratio of 2:1, then it is twice as wide as it is tall.
The aspect ratio formula is width divided by height: r = w / h.

Source: https://study.com/academy/lesson/aspect-ratio-definition-calculation.html (emphasis added)
If you divide 480 by 640, the result is 0.75, or 3 : 4.
Then why do I see it described as being a 4 : 3 aspect ratio in several places? (e.g. Android Camera, Google)
Would anyone be able to explain this please?

Cameras , Displays , Papers can be oriented in at least 2 ways : Portrait & Landscape.
Common terms like width & height become ambiguous when orientation is not known or can be changed at will.
Hence the technical way to "Define" aspect ratio is with "longest side:shortest side"
This number is always 1 or more.
Orientation will not effect that calculation.
{ Check out : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio }
Hence $480 \times 640$ & $640 \times 480$ can be described as $4:3$

When Orientation can not be changed at will , the alternate "Definition" for aspect ratio is used in CSS , HTML , SVG & such. There , it is indeed "width:height" where width is horizontal & height is vertical.
This number can be 1 or more or less.
{ Check out : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio }

Naturally , care should be taken when mixing these two use cases !!
